# Remove "Not Connected" suffix from visual studio tabs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

When I open up a script without a database connection Visual Studio puts this stupid message in the tab text of "Not Connected"

[image: This suffix is stupid]

It takes up half the space on a tab, often sacrificing meaningful parts of the name to display information I don't care about. There's a status bar that says disconnected, that's all I need.

In Options > Database Tools > Transact-SQL Editor, under tab text there's options to remove database name, login name and server name but none seem to remove this message.

Does anyone know how to remove it?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have it!

1. Right click on a sql file
2. Choose open with
3. Choose Source Code (Text) Editor
4. Click "Set as default" then click OK

Now this will also take away a lot of other features (like being able to execute the query) but I prefer to use Management Studio for running queries.

Comment: When I'm in VS 2010, open Source Code Explorer, and right-click a .sql file... I don't have an "Open With" option. Am I missing a step? I've already associated .sql files with a plain text editor outside of Visual Studio, so that's not it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to remove this useless text.  The funny thing is you can turn off all the other options and get a tab that has nothing but "not connected".  No way to get rid of "not connected" though.

You can vote to have an option added:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/658511/option-to-show-hide-the-not-connected-text-on-sql-tabs-when-not-using-vs-to-cno

Answer (score 0):

With [Tabs Studio add-in](http://www.tabsstudio.com) (developed by me), you can configure tabs text to remove the " - not connected" part.

Comment: This is very nice, but commercial.  Most minor extensions like this are not commercial.  Good work though.